# Parsing dates error

Tags: c#

```
string temp = dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].ToolTipText;//stored in dd-MM-yy hh:mm:ss
           //MessageBox.Show(temp);
temp = temp[0].ToString() + temp[1].ToString() + temp[2].ToString() + temp[3].ToString() + 
temp[4].ToString() + temp[5].ToString() + temp[6].ToString() + temp[7].ToString() + 
temp[8].ToString() + temp[9].ToString();//converting to dd-MM-yyyy
labeldate = DateTime.ParseExact(temp,"dd-MM-yyyy",
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I use the above code to convert string (dd/mm/yyyy format) into datetime type. It works fine on my computer. But the same gives an error on other computers saying string was not recognized as datetime. On further investigation. I saw that in other computers temp showed 1/1/2013 or 11/3/2013 whereas on mine it would show 01-01-2013 or 11-03-2013. I can't seem to solve this. Any help?

Comment: What the?? all that string character manipulation should be done with a `string.Remove(9)`. Show us the format of `temp` after you do your character manipulation, then it would be easier to assist you.

Comment: Your code is utterly nonsensical. What on earth is that second statement doing?

Comment: Yes, the crucial piece of information is how temp is formed. Without this, it's hard to advice anything but making sure that it is always in the same format.

Comment: After pondering for 5 minutes, my only guess can be that the second statement is a very poor man's form of `Substring(0,10)`.

Comment: Also, the initial format is `dd-MM-yy`, how do you suddenly get `dd-MM-yyyy` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely a culture issue. Use `.ToString(CultureInfo.InvarientCulture)` and you'll get the  same result regardless of the culture set on the computer.

Comment: He already uses this and also he specified that what his *source* (temp) is different. In this case InvariantCulture won't help.

Comment: temp is different, but temp is being populated by lots of .ToString() calls which could change depending on the culture.

Comment: IMO, this answer doesn't deserve a downvote, It is a culture issue, where date separator is `/` or `-` depending on the culture, Using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` while assigning date to `ToolTipText` would sovle the issue

Answer (score 3):

If all you are doing is trying to get the date portion of the date time you can simplify your code to

```
string temp = dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].ToolTipText;//stored in dd-MM-yy hh:mm:ss
labeldate = DateTime.Parse(temp).Date;
```

As for the culture problem wilsjd mentioned. If `ToolTipText` is using the default culture rules for however that text is being entered the parser should use the same rule when it tries to parse it back out.